# Como printar o resultado de uma query no python sem as aspas e parenteses?

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

Estou usando SQL Server e tkinter no python, então queria printar as informações geradas pelo comando:

```
self.linhas = self.cursor.execute("""
                        SELECT codigo, preco, produto, tipo, quantidade, tamanho FROM Estoque 
                        ORDER BY codigo ASC;
                    """)
```

, na trueview do tkinter, mas as mesmas ficam sem formatação, com virgulas, parênteses, etc.
Como mostra nessa print:

print = https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVDuZ.png

Ali podemos ver que é printado dessa forma = (1, '1', 'a', 'a', 1, '1'), (1, '1', 'dsf', 'sdf', 1, '1'), (1, '1', 'daw', 'adw', 1, '1'), (123, '1', 'afds', 'fsad', 123, '123')

Mas eu queria ocultar essas aspas, virgulas, etc. Ficando na trueview somente os elementos.

Abaixo esta minha função usada para capturar informações do banco de dados e printar elas na trueview:

```
def selectList(self):
    
    self.trueview.delete(*self.trueview.get_children())
    self.connectDB()
    
    self.linhas = self.cursor.execute("""
                        SELECT codigo, preco, produto, tipo, quantidade, tamanho FROM Estoque 
                        ORDER BY codigo ASC;
                    """)


    self.list = self.cursor.fetchall()

    for i in self.list:
        self.trueview.insert("", END, values=i) 

    self.disconnectDB()
    self.cleanWindow()
```

Answer (score -2):

Me parece que você está tentando colocar a lista inteira em uma coluna só, ai fica como string, construi um exemplo, espero que ajude...

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        columns = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')

        api_result = [(1, '1', 'a', 'a', 1, '1'), (1, '1', 'dsf', 'sdf', 1, '1'),
                      (1, '1', 'daw', 'adw', 1, '1'),
                      (123, '1', 'afds', 'fsad', 123, '123')]

        tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=columns)
        tree.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        for y, col in enumerate(columns):
            tree.heading(column=col, text=col)
            
        for i, x in enumerate(api_result):
            tree.insert("", END, values=x)


app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

[Exemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpPQd.png)